# ¿Cómo descargar una imagen usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy empezando a aprender javascript y a modo de práctica quiero saber como poder descargar una imagen ("por ejemplo el logo de google") de Internet usando javascript guardándolo en mi equipo.

Comment: A qué se refiere con descargar?.... para mostrarla en un div o en un img o para que se guarde en un directorio del equipo?

Comment: Lo que quiero es que se guarde en mi equipo.

Comment: Agrega una breve descripción de lo que has buscado/investigado y agrega más detalles sobre lo que va a hacer que se ejecute la descarga. ¿Será cuando se cargue la página, cuando se le de clic a un botón, cuando el usuario pestañee... ? Referencia [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crea un elemento `a` y añade el atributo `download` para que se pueda descargar, luego ejecuta el evento `click` para que se puede descargar en tu equipo.

```js
var source = 'https://www.google.es/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';

var a = document.createElement('a');

a.download = true;
a.target = '_blank';
a.href= source;

a.click();
```

Comment: Esto solo funciona en Chrome, tienes algo multiplataforma ?

Comment: no solo en chrome, https://caniuse.com/#search=a%20download